# Error publishing workflow in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

When publishing a workflow in SharePoint 2010 Designer I received the following error.

> Errors were found when compiling the
>   workflow.The workflow files were saved
>   but cannot be run.

Check For Errors indicated the workflow was fine

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by Alternate Access Mappings not being configured correctly.

I was accessing the site using the url `http://mysharepoint.mynetwork.local`, however alternate access mappings were only configured for `http://mysharepoint` and `http://localhost`

Once I added an alternate access mapping for `http://mysharepoint.mynetwork.local` it published fine.